# Print 'all' full Lists when a certain characters exist within the element of a string

Tags: python-2.7

```
a = [['ab', 'cd'], ['cd'], ['cd', 'ef']

for line in a:
    if 'c' in line:
        print line
```

See above code. How can I print the lines that contain the character 'c'. I can only get a result if the full string within the element is present.

Comment: I still don't understand what you want.. Are you trying to print out all the lists which include elements that have a _c_ in them? Or are you trying to print out just the strings which consist of a _c_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know exactly what you want but I tried covering both scenarios.

**Scenario I: Get the full list which has elements consisting of character**

You have a list of lists. When iterating over `a`, you are now accessing the second list.

With your current code, you are checking to see if *c* exists inside the contents of `a`. It obviously doesn't because `a` consists of another list and not string. You need to iterate over the second list and perform character existence check on it as shown below.

```
a = [['ab', 'cd'], ['cd'], ['cd', 'ef'], ['ar'], ['tu'], ['ip', 'cr']]

for list in a: #this loop accesses the second list
  for element in list: #this accesses the actual elements i.e. 'ab, cd' etc
    if 'c' in element:
      print list
```

**Output**

```
['ab', 'cd']
['cd']
['cd', 'ef']
['ip', 'cr']
```

**Scenario II: Get the full string which consists of character**

Same code as above. Replace `print list` with `print element`

**Output**

```
cd
cd
cd
cr
```

Comment: Scenario I: Get the full list which has elements consisting of character is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
a = (['ab', 'cd'], ['cd'], ['cd', 'ef'])


for i in range(0,3):
    for j in range(0, len(a[i])):
        if 'c' in a[i][j]:
            print a[i][j]
```

This works if you are only trying to print the specific element within the lists; in this case the output is

```
cd
cd
cd
```

Answer (score 0):

when iterating over a, check if character 'c' is present in joined items.
This would work if a is list of lists.

```
a = [['ab', 'cd'], ['cd'], ['cd', 'ef']

for item in a:
    if 'c' in "".join(item):
        print item
```

Comment: You beat me to it.. Was about to add this as an alternative. :)

Comment: Thanks for your kind words eshirima :)